# SQL QUERY not picking up EXCEL date parameter not functional

Tags: microsoft-excel, power, query, power-query

I have an overnight data set that needs refreshing everyday. I used today's date with format =NOW() and tomorrow's date as =NOW()+1. The query is not pulling up the date from cell reference despite the set parameters, instead it's just using present date making me assume it's not using the parameters.

However it is pulling the HOURs and MINUTES correctly. (I also have hour by hour parameters that are functional).

I have tried changing cell format holding the dates to  text, general, short date or number and this doesn't help.

The parameters within the URL fall under htttps//:www......=["Start Date",""]........=["End Date",""]

Any guidance will be appreciated. Using Office 365

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

Used the following formula for date rather the one shown on question :

=TEXT(INT(NOW()-0.5),"yyyy/mm/dd")